# How to display image to button on codebehind in silverlight depending upon condition?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

> How do i display or show image to button using code behind in silverlight 
>   depending upon condition?

i'm new bie.

> there are some conditions depending upon that i need to show
>   image on button please help.`

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Width="24" Height="24">
    <Image Source="myImage.png" Stretch="None"/>
</Button>
```

> How can i change image source depending upon condition in code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Width="24" Height="24"> 
    <Image x:Name="myImage" Source="myImage.png" Stretch="None"/> 
</Button>
```

Then do:

```
if (someCondition)
{
    myImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
else
{
    myImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Does that work for you?